# How can i refactor this nested if on scala

Tags: scala, if-statement, case

i have this nested if in scala

```
   if (collection != "h" && emptyColumns.contains(collection)) {
      message += s"$collection is null"
      //Id is not null
    } else if (emptyColumns.length >= schemaWithoutAddedColumns.length) {
      message += s"The ID ${row.getAs(collection)} is the only valid Field"
    } else {
      message = ""
    }
```

How could i refactor it into pattern matching.

Thanks! i'm kinda new to scala.

Comment: The code seems perfectly fine to me, and I don't see how you can turn it into a beautiful pattern matching.

Comment: Since the two ifs are checking properties on different variables, I do not see any reason to convert this into a pattern match. I would even think it is more readable using ifs. BTW, I would be more concerned by the mutating message.